# Need help installing Micromax Modem MMX210G

Tags: command-line, gnome-terminal

How can I install Micromax MMX210G Modem on Ubuntu 14.04.1?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! ;-) Could you please give us a bit more information like: what version of Ubuntu you're running? What the error message is?  Please [edit] your question and add this information...

Answer (score 1):

[How to Configure Micromax 3g Modem on Ubuntu 12.04, 12.10 And 13.04](http://imacify.com/2012/10/how-to-configure-micromax-3g-modem-on-ubuntu-12-10/)

1. Finding the Product ID of the USB Modem

Plugin the USB modem to the Computer
Open the Terminal (ctrl+alt+t)
Type the command lsusb (This lists the active USB devices connected to the computer along with the Product ID and the Vendor name)
Make a note of the Product ID and Vendor name

2. Editing the content of  Modules.

In the Terminal, type the following command to edit the “modules” file
sudo gedit /etc/modules (Type your administrator password if it asks for). Clear all the content and replace it with new content shown below:

```
             # /etc/modules: kernel modules to load at boot time.
             #
             # This file contains the names of kernel modules that should be loaded
             # at boot time, one per line. Lines beginning with “#” are ignored.
             loop
             lp
             rtc
             usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605
             option
```

(Change the vendor and product value if it is different for your USB modem, You can get this values in 1step Terminal window)

3. Editing the content of usb_modeswitch.d
   In Terminal, type the command

   ```
            gksudo gedit /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e:9605
   ```

The command opens the text file with the above mentioned name in the text editor.

Add the following lines to that file and save it.

```
             DefaultVendor = 0x1c9e
             DefaultProduct = 0x9605
             TargetVendor = 0x1c9e
             TargetProduct = 0x9605
             MessageContent=”55534243123456788000000080000606f50402527000000000000000000000″
```

Close the text editor

(These values are only for the Micromax MMX352G Model. Change the values as per your device if you are using the different one)

Execute these commands in the terminal as root user to configure the modem.

```
             modprobe usbserial vendor=0x1c9e product=0x9605 

             usb_modeswitch -c /etc/usb_modeswitch.d/1c9e\:9605
```

4.Create a mobile Broadband connection

Open Network Connection Manager, Click the Add button on the Mobile Broadband tab, Create a new mobile broadband connection using the wizard appeared. Add the appropriate country, service provider, plan and just finish the wizard after selecting the appropriate name for the connection. (Be careful in selecting the plan)

After restarting process finish the login and wait for few minutes. It would take some time to configure so please be patient. The new mobile broadband connection is visible and available on the network connection list. Connect to the Internet by clicking on that.

### Now your Internet is Connected with your USB Modem on Ubuntu 12.04.

For Ubuntu  12.10 and 13.04: Open the Terminal. Change to root user using the su command.

Ubuntu 12.10

```
             echo 1c9e 9605 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/option1/new_id
```

Ubuntu 13.04

```
             echo 1c9e 9605 > /sys/bus/usb-serial/drivers/generic/new_id
```

Wait for a while it will take some time . You will see your  your modem connection  visible on the default connection.

Note: If you want to run the command automatically whenever the system starts add the above code to the file rc.local before the line exit 0.

To edit the rc.local file use the command.

```
             sudo gedit /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: While this may theoretically answer the question, it is preferred that you include the relevant bits of the site here or similar in order to provide a full answer even if the link goes away or breaks going forward.

Comment: Although your answer is 100% correct, it might also become 100% useless if that link is moved, changed, merged into another one or the main site just disappears... :-( Therefore, please [edit] your answer, and copy the relevant steps from the link into your answer, thereby guaranteeing your answer for 100% of the lifetime of this site! ;-) You can always leave the link in at the bottom of your answer as a source for your material...